# How do I use sqlite3 PRAGMA user_version in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, pragma

I am trying to check the user_version of the sqlite DB.  I have an admin tool to bump the version, but I don't understand the syntax of the pragma statement.  I am expecting to test the value in an if-statement.  Can someone provide a code sample?  When I embed the pragma statement in my objective-c code, the compiler throws an error.

Comment: I updated my answer with examples.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured it out with the inspiration from newtover, digging into FMDB and re-reading the *sqlite3* documentation (it is still very vague in my opinion).  This code returns the value that I bumped in the admin tool when I make notable changes to the schema that require migration.

```
-(int)queryUserVersion: (sqlite3*) db {
    // get current database version of schema
    static sqlite3_stmt *stmt_version;
    int databaseVersion;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "PRAGMA user_version;", -1, &stmt_version, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(stmt_version) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            databaseVersion = sqlite3_column_int(stmt_version, 0);
            NSLog(@"%s: version %d", __FUNCTION__, databaseVersion);
        }
        NSLog(@"%s: the databaseVersion is: %d", __FUNCTION__, databaseVersion);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%s: ERROR Preparing: , %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(db) );
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt_version);

    return databaseVersion;
}
```

I have a similar method for the schema version where the sql-statement is changed to `"PRAGMA schema_version;"`

Comment: It's not a good idea to touch schema_version : http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version

Comment: @AntonChikin by touch, do you mean "read-only"?  I thought the purpose of having a version was to read and test the value.  I don't intend to modify it.  Buy why shouldn't I touch it.

Comment: @mobibob The sqlite website that Anton linked has the answer to your question, check out the schema_version section, second paragraph: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version

Comment: @davidfg4 like I thought (I read this back in 2010) the warning is against modifying.  There isn't any issue with read-only,  "...using "PRAGMA schema_version" to modify the schema-version..."

Comment: @mobibob How can I update user_version of sqlite programatically ?

Answer (score 4):

Pragma statements [can not](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#pragma-stmt) be used within other statements (there are no references to pragma-stmt from other statements).

But you can use the user_version value by making two requests: querying pragma and using the selected value as literal in the next query.

**UPD**: if you are interested in PRAGMA syntax, it is rather simple:

```
sqlite> pragma user_version=10;
sqlite> pragma user_version;
user_version
------------------------------
10
sqlite> pragma user_version='12.3.124';
sqlite> pragma user_version;
user_version
------------------------------
12
```

That is the result will come as a row with a single value.

If you are interested in a way to issue statements to SQLite in objective-c, try looking at [neighbour questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone+sqlite): [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587068/inserting-nil-values-into-sqlite-database). Unfortunatelly, I've never coded in objective-c.

Comment: OK, I am with you so far.  But help me out a bit further, are you saying that I do something like: sqlite3_prepare_v2(PRAGMA user_version); char *ver = sqlite_column_text(1); can you provide some code -- I don't understand the doc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using FMDB wrapper (which is recommended if you don't want to deal with C handler interface of sqlite)

Use

```
[self.db setUserVersion:yourUserVersion]; // yourUserVersion is of uint32_t type
```

To read current user_version user

```
[self.db userVersion];                   // returned value is of uint32_t type
```

Documentation:

http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Categories/FMDatabase+FMDatabaseAdditions.html

This answer is basically copy of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27807125/1364174