# identify if android or windows at runtime in sql

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, windows

Ok, basically we (the company I work for) are building a new **Warehouse Management System** to pick and pull orders. I am designing for the Android side of things and my co-worker is designing for Windows Mobile.

Is there a way at runtime (in SQL) to determine what OS we are using? i.e., whether it is *Android* or *Windows Mobile*?

Comment: Does it matter what OS you are on? Your data will remain the same on both, right?

Comment: Is this a web app? Use the user-agent string from the request headers?

Comment: You are using SQLite on Windows Mobile as well? What version of Windows Mobile?

Comment: @RaghavSood no it does not matter what os the data does remain the same we just do not want to maintain 2 completely different codes in sql. cdonner yes we are... its version 6.5 i believe for windows mobile. not positive as I am mainly dealing with android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help in your specific situation, but you could use the PRAGMA construct ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659797/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-pragma-user-version-in-objective-c)) either by setting **user_version** during installation to something that has the platform encoded (or just use a regular table in your schema for this), or the (deprecated!) **data_store_directory** that probably points to different locations depending on the platform.

Comment: this seems to be working i will put it thru more test this weekend. thank you!