# import if database not exist in iOS sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite

My problem is it always import sqlite database (it has so many setup data already) from resources file whenever render my app. First time I render my apps, it import sqlite database from resource file and I insert some data into the table. But second time render again, it import again and lost my inserted records. Following is my coding.

What I want to it does not need to import if database exist.

```
static NaWinDatabase *_database;

+ (NaWinDatabase*)database {
    if (_database == nil) {
        _database = [[NaWinDatabase alloc] init];
    }
    return _database;
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nawin" ofType:@"sqlite3"];

        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_database) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database!");
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyDatabaseIfNeeded` will copy your resource database to the application directory folder if it is not copied for the first time

```
+ (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success) {

        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];

        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message \"%@\".", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

//Path that saves your database in application document directory

```
 + (NSString *) getDBPath {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the SQLite DB exists at app launch and if it does not then import it, if it does exist do not import. The SQLite DB is just a file.

Comment: can you give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3's `sqlite3_open` succeeds whether or not the file exists.

I assume your database is created from SQL. If so and you want to see if the database has been set up yet, you can do a `pragma schema_version;` query against the database connection. If it returns 0, there are no tables yet. Any other value, and you've created the tables.

Make sure your table creation and record insertion are atomic and you should have no further troubles.

Comment: can you give me show coding as example or correct me my existing coding

Comment: Something like this, but schema_version instead of user_version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659797/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-pragma-user-version-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used sqlite on iOS recently but I recall having to open the database in the document directory. I believe for security reasons the main bundle can not be modified. Essentially your database is read only.

I do something like:

```
    NSString *docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *dbPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
    fmdb = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [fmdb open];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may be help full... It's working fine

```
    - (void)copyDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // First, test for existence.
       BOOL success;
       NSFileManager *fileManager      =   [NSFileManager defaultManager];
       NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths                  =   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory    =   [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    writableDBPath                  =   [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"carDatabase.sqlite"];

    success                         =   [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success)
        return;
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath         =   [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"carDatabase.sqlite"];
    success                         =   [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Result For Database path %c",success);
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    NSLog(@"Result For Database path %c",success);
}

//Get DataBase Path
- (NSString *) getDBPath {
    NSString *sqLiteDb = writableDBPath ; // [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"liveonmap_iphone" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    return sqLiteDb;
}
```

Cheers...