# Trying to open encrypted database returns error code 26

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using an encrypted database. It's getting open and checks the key. But on `PRAGMA user_version;` it returns error code 26.

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2(dbpath, &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE| SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(sqlite3_key(database, [key UTF8String], strlen([key UTF8String])) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *tString = @"PRAGMA user_version;";
        int resultCode = sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [tString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);
     }
}
```

Comment: you need to check this how to use `PRAGMA user_version;` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659797/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-pragma-user-version-in-objective-c

Comment: I have used the raw query execution. but still i am receiving the same error the error: failed to execute pragma statement with message 'file is encrypted or is not a database'.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 26 is `SQLITE_NOTADB`. Your key might not be correct. According to the documentation:

> If you specify an incorrect key, you will not get an error message right away. But the first time you try to access the database you will get an `SQLITE_NOTADB` error with a message of "file is encrypted or is not a database".

Comment: The database is in open state. But when am executing the query , receiving the error: failed to execute pragma statement with message 'file is encrypted or is not a database'.

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior you'll see if the key was incorrect.